# Surface area of a solid generated by revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, 3d

Well I know my question already has answers, but I was not able to follow them.
Let us say that we have rotated the function y = $x^3$ around x-axis to obtain something like the image.

[image]

Now we want to find the surface area from x = 1 to x = 2.

The book says that the formula is:
$2\pi\int_1^2x^3\sqrt{1+9x^4}dx $
or in general, the surface area in these type of questions is:
$2\pi\int_a^bf(x)\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx $

I don't know why we need to take the length of the curve into account. The question requires splitting the solid into infinite cylinders with infinetesmially small width(dx). The radius of the circle is f(x). So, the curved surface area of 1 such cylinder must be $2\pi f(x)dx$. Therefore, the total surface area is:

$\int_a^b2\pi f(x)dx = 2\pi\int_a^bf(x)dx$

I don't know what is wrong with my approach or why should we take the arc length into consideration. Intuitively, my reasoning seems right.

Please answer in a simpler way as integrals have never been my strength.

Comment: The width of the cylinder you have to consider is not $dx$. It is $\sqrt{df^2+dx^2}=\sqrt{(f')^2+1}\,dx\,.$ The width $dx$ is only its projection on to the $x$-axis. When you zoom into the representative band of your picture and apply the Pythagorean theorem this should become clear. Or in other words: the correct width of the cylinder is in fact the length of the curve $(x,f(x))$ when $x$ moves from $x$ to $x+dx$.

Comment: @KurtG. your reasoning seems right but since we are breaking it into infinitesimal pieces, length of curve doesn't matter as the width would be a very small part of x or dx.

Comment: Even in the infinitesimal world not every $dy$ equals $dx$. You should consider $f(x)=x$ where you can work with noninfinitesimal $\Delta x$ and $\Delta f$ to convince yourself what the right approach is.

Comment: well I get what you're saying and maybe you're right but is there a formal proof or something of this method?

Comment: That formal proof would be the same as the one for the length of a curve: approximate the curve by piecewise linear segments, calculate the length of each by Pythagoras and take the limit.